# Trying to identify a mystery set, mostly black and dark grey

Tags: set-identification

I purchased a lot from Facebook that included a few fully complete with box sets as well as two bags with what certainly appears to be a full set. I started adding several of the more unique ones to rebrickable, but I either need to add a lot more, or I'm doing it wrong. This is my first time at this, so either is entirely possible.

Any ideas or leads would be appreciated. So far I'm leaning towards a Sith Star Wars or Batman kit given the colors. The assembled piece has a twin that is pretty much identical. The only unique pieces I found were a cockpit dashboard thing and the windshield design. The rest were sticker free, and there were no figures included.

[image: Dark grey and some red pieces.]

[image: Mostly black and dark grey.]

[image: Two of these were still assembled, reminds me of the jets on the SR71 a bit.]

Comment: Here's a list of some of the more unique parts from the black pile. 
 https://rebrickable.com/users/DakMorgan/partlists/232220/

Comment: I suspect this to be a mix of parts. For example, last picture shows [Black Slope 45 4 x 4 Double with Hinge](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4857&colorID=11&in=A) in Black and none of those sets have some of Dark Gray/Dark Bluish Gray pieces found in that assembly. There isn't that much of sets in dark shades of gray included with Trans-Black Windscreen see on second picture too.

Comment: I saw that as well, maybe it's from a MOC?  I wonder if there's an easy way to find out what the assembled parts are for at least?

Comment: Looks like it's all a MOC - as Alex mentioned, there's only two sets that contain two of that element, and neither of them come with dark grey cylinders or cones :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is a cohesive set, but all the parts scream 2005 era Star Wars.

There is a x-wing canopy that gives me that idea, but the real smoking gun is the color combination of parts. There appears to be a lot of old (warm) dark grey, prior to Lego changing to the more (cool) bley they use today.

I think its just stray parts from that era. Enjoy all that classic dark grey, its great for mixing in with modern greys.

Comment: I think these are primarily Dark Bluish Grey rather than Dark Grey. For example this piece doesn't exist in Dark Grey https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43712#T=C

Answer (score 0):

While the last image looks like a partial build of an official set, the [Slope 45° 4 x 4 Double with Hinge - Black](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4857/slope-45-4-x-4-double-with-hinge/0/) piece was only ever released in 4 sets, none of which have the windscreen piece mentioned by Roger. Therefore the collection can't belong to a single official set.

[image]

Comment: The windscreen and the tan 1x2 hinge plates in the build are likely both from this set https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4500-1#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0} ; the tan hinges exist in very few other sets